# How to turn zipcode into coordinates with geodjango?

Tags: django, geodjango

I am having trouble understanding the documentation on geodjango.  First of all using the zipcode example:

```
class Zipcode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    poly = models.PolygonField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Is PolygonField where I would store the actual long/lattitude coordinates of the zipcode?  The other question is how would I actually translate the zipcode into those coordinates?  That is the one step I cannot figure out how to do.

I assume I'm going to need to convert the zipcode into coordinates and then compare those against other coordinates to determine 'nearest zipcodes to location x', which is what I'm trying to do.

On a side note, I found https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities, which seems like I would be able to accomplish this WITHOUT converting zipcodes into coordinates, but there isn't really any documentation, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

GeoDjango does not handle converting zip codes into locations: that's simply not what it's for. You'll need a geocoding library, a Google search should reveal plenty.

The project you link to simply uses an existing set of geocoded data for cities and zip codes, and even tells you where to get it - see the relevant [management command](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities/blob/master/cities/management/commands/cities.py).